# Guardar direccion de descarga de imagen en Firebase Storage en Firebase DataBase

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, nosql

Contruyo una app donde en un activity puedes escoger una foto subirla y luego subir tus otros datos como nombre edad etc.
Mi codigo comienza pidiendo que selecciones una foto de donde quieras y despues la recortas luego se sube al Storage de Firebase, hasta aqui no hay problemas tanto la imagen como los datos suben correctamente. el problema es a la hora de guardar la url de descarga de la foto en la base de datoos de firebase para luego pedirlo y mostrar la foto de perfil. 
Esto es lo que se guarda: 
[image: Base de datos firebase]

Tengo el siguiente codigo Activity (RegisterDataActivity.java):

```
final static int Gallery_Pick = 1;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private DatabaseReference UsersRef;
private StorageReference UserProfileImageRef;
String currentUserID;

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == Gallery_Pick && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null ){

        Uri ImageUri = data.getData();
        CropImage.activity(ImageUri)
                .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                .setAspectRatio(1,1)
                .start(this);
    }
    if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE){
        CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            loadingBar.setTitle("Cargando imagen");
            loadingBar.setMessage("Por favor espere, mientras actualizamos su foto de perfil.");
            loadingBar.show();
            loadingBar.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
            final Uri resultUri = result.getUri();
            final StorageReference filePath = UserProfileImageRef.child(currentUserID+".jpg");
            filePath.putFile(resultUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()){
                        Toast.makeText(RegisterDataActivity.this,"Foto de perfil guardada", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        final String downloadUrl = task.getResult().getStorage().getDownloadUrl().toString();
                        UsersRef.child("profileimage").setValue(downloadUrl)
                                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                        if (task.isSuccessful()){
                                            ReintentRegisterData();
                                            Toast.makeText(RegisterDataActivity.this, "Foto de perfil guardada",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            loadingBar.dismiss();
                                        }else{
                                            String message = task.getException().getMessage();
                                            Toast.makeText(RegisterDataActivity.this, "Error:"+ message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            loadingBar.dismiss();
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                    }
                }
            });

        }else{
            Toast.makeText(RegisterDataActivity.this, "Error: La imagen no se pudo recortar intentalo otra vez.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            loadingBar.dismiss();
        }
    }


}

 private void inicializaUI(){

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    currentUserID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    UsersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(currentUserID);
    UserProfileImageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("Profile Images");
    //Country Picker
    countryPicker = new CountryPicker.Builder().with(this)
            .listener(this)
            .build();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deberias hacerlo de la siguiente forma utilizando Task

```
  final StorageReference filePath = UserProfileImageRef.child(currentUserID+".jpg");
                filePath.putFile(resultUri).continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
        @Override
        public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
           //Preguntamos si el task de subir la imagen fue exitoso, si lo es retornamos la url de descarga del archivo subido , sino lanzamos una exception.
              if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                throw task.getException();
            }

            return filePath.getDownloadUrl();
        }.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                    //Luego si se utiliza addOnCompleteListener para obtener ese enlace
                      if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                       //Obtenemos el uri del enlace
                        Uri downloadUrl = task.getResult();
                        Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: Enlace de descarga" + 
                        downloadUri.toString() );

                UsersRef.child("profileimage").setValue(downloadUrl.toString())
                                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                        if (task.isSuccessful()){
                                            ReintentRegisterData();
                                            Toast.makeText(RegisterDataActivity.this, "Foto de perfil guardada",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            loadingBar.dismiss();
                                        }else{
                                            String message = task.getException().getMessage();
                                            Toast.makeText(RegisterDataActivity.this, "Error:"+ message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            loadingBar.dismiss();
                                        }
                                    }
                                });


                    } else {
                                          Toast.makeText(mContext, "upload failed: " + task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                }
            });
```

De esta manera deberia funcionar, lo que hacemos es usar Task para retornar el estado de la operacion antes de obtener el enlace de descarga, y luego, cuando ese return nos dio el enlace de descarga de ese archivo, podemos recien hacer la logica para subir ese enlace a nuestro Database.

Para mas info te dejo la documentacion

- [public Task getDownloadUrl ()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageReference#getDownloadUrl())