# Cómo obtener URL https y no la gs en Firebase?

Tags: android-studio, firebase

Hola llevo un tiempo buscando como obtener el url https: de Storage pero lo único que encuentro solo es para sacar el gs: Como puedo obtener este url en código de android studio?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¡Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Podes obtener el enlace de descarga de la siguiente manera

```
 storageRef.child("tu_direccion_a_la_foto/blkbl....jpg").getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
            // Conseguimos el enlace de descarga
            Uri downloadUri = taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getDownloadUrl();
            String urlFoto = downloadUri.toString(); //El enlace a la foto hecho string
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
            // Manejamos algun error
        }
    });
```

Estoy asumiendo que estos archivos los queres buscar poniendolos en Storage de Firebase, recuerda que `.child("tu_direccion_a_la_foto/blkbl....jpg")` es el path donde esta guardada esa foto en Firebase Storage. Si deseas obtener el enlace de la foto subida y almacenarlo en Firebase Database, te recomiendo seguir **[esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/205227/guardar-direccion-de-descarga-de-imagen-en-firebase-storage-en-firebase-database/205751#205751)** respuesta.

Para mas info de como obtener el enlace de descarga segui este [LINK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files#download_data_via_url)